# How to deserialize a XML file to a C# object (.svg) successfully?

Tags: c#, svg, replace, xml-deserialization

I want to add text to a icon and use that icon on a website where the icon is shown with added text inside. As an example: think of a cloud-icon with a number in it where the number is the precipitation probability. The value of that number changes so it must be possible to change the text dynamically.

I use Inkscape.org as a drawing program that creates a `.svg` file. It is kind of XML, I guess. I thought I just use a online converter from .xml -> C# object classes (https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net) and deserialize it then change one value and serialize it again if possible in to memory and then use that as an image on a webpage. But I get an error at the deserialization step

> [http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>](http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27%3E) was not expected.

I did try different class models - but nothing worked. I am unsure if I am pursuing the right solution.

I want to be able to have a scalable icon with text in it and I must be able to change the text in the icon and show it to website users.

What shall I do?

I just want to be able to edit the last line of the `.svg` dynamically. Or do I have to go a different route like `icon.svg` as background and `number.svg` on top (two files instead of one)?

Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated

Here is the `.svg` file of the cloud icon with added text "Test", I would like to be able to change "Test" in a different string in C#:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m20.8403 4.4685c-.5663-2.3963-2.6273-4.1744-5.0903-4.1744-2.8995 0-5.25 2.4616-5.25 5.5001 0 .1964.0113.3896.03.5799-.8955.3771-1.53 1.2924-1.53 2.3664 0 1.4097 1.0913 2.5535 2.4375 2.5535h9.3c1.8023 0 3.2625-1.5305 3.2625-3.4179 0-1.8509-1.4063-3.3493-3.1597-3.4076" fill="#e5e5e5" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
  <circle clip-rule="evenodd" cx="15.533335" cy="9.787135" fill="#ffd02f" fill-rule="evenodd" r="6"/>
  <path d="m3.6992 20.6764c-1.7637 0-3.1992-1.4297-3.1992-3.187 0-1.3047.7881-2.4639 2.0088-2.9531l.3496-.1401-.0391-.375c-.0264-.2578-.043-.52-.043-.7856 0-4.103 3.3496-7.4414 7.4678-7.4414 3.4375 0 6.4141 2.3223 7.2402 5.6479l.0918.3672.3779.0117c2.417.0767 4.3105 2.0186 4.3105 4.4209 0 2.4453-1.9971 4.4346-4.4512 4.4346h-14.1141z" fill="#fff"/>
  <path d="m10.2441 6.2941c3.2066 0 5.9842 2.1664 6.7547 5.2684l.1824.7346.7565.0239c2.1459.0677 3.827 1.7899 3.827 3.9207 0 2.1697-1.7726 3.9348-3.9514 3.9348h-14.114c-1.4884-.0001-2.6993-1.2054-2.6993-2.6871 0-1.0995.6649-2.0764 1.694-2.4888l.7005-.2806-.0778-.7506c-.027-.261-.0402-.5011-.0402-.7341 0-3.8274 3.1256-6.9412 6.9676-6.9412m0-1c-4.4004 0-7.9677 3.5543-7.9677 7.9412 0 .2836.0171.5627.0455.8372-1.3589.5446-2.3219 1.8662-2.3219 3.4169 0 2.0353 1.6561 3.687 3.6993 3.687h14.1141c2.7352 0 4.9514-2.2099 4.9514-4.9348 0-2.6729-2.1342-4.8361-4.7954-4.9202-.8595-3.46-3.9873-6.0273-7.7253-6.0273z" fill="#1d1d33"/>
  <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m18.606967 8.7411167c-.5663-2.3963-2.6273-4.1744-5.0903-4.1744-2.8995 0-5.25 2.4616-5.25 5.5001003 0 .1964.0113.3896.03.5799-.8955.3771-1.53 1.2924-1.53 2.3664 0 1.4097 1.0913 2.5535 2.4374997 2.5535h9.3000003c1.8023 0 3.2625-1.5305 3.2625-3.4179 0-1.8509-1.4063-3.3493003-3.1597-3.4076003" fill="#e5e5e5" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
  <text style="font-weight:bold;font-size:6.62016;font-family:monospace;letter-spacing:0;word-spacing:0;stroke-width:.354651" x="3.696808" y="17.625877">
    <tspan stroke-width=".354651" x="3.696808" y="17.625877">TEST</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: @AKX thanks for hint I try that. I will post an update here in a few hours ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't bother with XML (de)serialization or the SVG object model in a simple case like this.

Instead, just make the default text in Inkscape something like `PLACEHOLDER` (or anything else you know won't appear otherwise in the SVG XML), and use simple string replacement, i.e.

```
var svgXml = ReadThatXMLAsAString();
svgXml = svgXml.replace("PLACEHOLDER", "42");
EmitThatXMLToTheUserSomehow(svgXml);
```

Comment: As someone who has done programmatic changes to SVG in a script-like fashion (generating different images from a uniform template), I have to disagree. The easiest and most robust way of getting changes into the document has been XML parsing, selecting the desired elements by ID and replacing their content (or changing their properties). String replacements tend to be problematic with things that must be escaped and at that point the additional code you have to write is both error-prone and about the same length as doing it properly.

Comment: I've done such programmatic changes to SVG in a script-like fashion too. I do agree that for the more general case, parsing SVG into an XML document (not a tree of classes) you can manipulate with e.g. XPath will be better. However, here OP has simple images with simple number replacements, so this will suffice. OP can refactor to real XML when their needs change. (Not to mention engineering SVG files with correct element IDs, etc. takes more effort than just placing text :-) )

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need deserialized C# class instances here. Your search led you to something that may sound similar to a beginner (serialize and deserialize objects to/from XML), but it's completely unnecessary here.

Instead, as a rough outline of what you could do, [load the SVG as an XML document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var svg = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

Then select the element you want to change:

```
var tspan = (XText) svg.XPathSelectElement("//*[localName()='tspan']");
// Note: Above way of selecting the tspan is easier to start with
// because you don't have to care about namespaces
```

And change away:

```
tspan.Value = "New text";
```

And save it again in the end:

```
svg.Save(fileName);
```

May need some tweaking (can't test the code right now), but that's the rough idea.

Comment: Could you please help with this line: var tspan = (XText)svg.XPathSelectElement("//*[localName()='tspan']"); ERROR=XElement can not be converted to XText

Answer (score 0):

@AKX thanks so much!

Here the final code:

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"SvgTest.svg");

        var input = reader.ReadToEnd();
        
        //find the text that should be replaced
        input = input.Replace("TEST", "YES");
        reader.Close();
        
        //test -> yes the replace worked TEST->YES
        RtxbxShow.Text = input;

        //now show that svg icon in a picturebox (nuget https://github.com/vvvv/SVG)
        var mySvg = SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(input);
        PicbxShow2.Image = mySvg.Draw(240,240);
```

Comment: @Joey I have tried to parse the svg. to a c# Model but without success. Is there a easy way to do that? I have done somehting like that with json -> C# with online converter 
 (or  in VisualStudio under Edit past as XML Class) etc. But it fail with the .svg format! I still would like to see how that .svg file could be deserialized. Ups saw your answere just now